# understand and analyse the flink code, specially the scheduling part

Tags: streaming, apache-flink, flink-streaming, bigdata

I am working on improvement of the resource and tasks scheduling of apache flink, please share any tutorial or any document on the internal architecture of apache flink. Also share proper method of debuging the flink code.

Your help and experience of analyzing the flink code will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For how job scheduling works in Flink, I would start looking at https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.2/internals/job_scheduling.html. Generally, the last part of the current Flink documentation contains some good information about the internals of Apache Flink.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you share any information about understanding the coding structure of flink(not the working and general architecture), also to help me in coding the new changes to the default scheduler?

Comment: #GordonTai any suggestions in this regards?